# close datepicker menu using button-reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am new to `reactjs`. I have used a `date picker` from `ant js`.
When i clicked the `date picker`, it gets opened. In the `footer` of the menu, i have a `compare date` checkbox and a `range picker` attached with it. If the user clicks the `check box`, the `compare date picker` gets activated.
In bottom side, I have a `submit` and `cancel` button.
Here's the picture, how it looks like,

[image]

My Question is When i select and drag the range in the `above date picker`, the menu gets closed automatically and the selected `range date` was assigned. But i don't need the `datepicker menu` to be automatically closed after selection. It should be closed only  when the user clicks the `submit` button. I know `open` props helps me to handle this. I read the documentation https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#header .But I don't know how to use in this case.

I also need a verification which is, if the user ticks the  `compare with` check box, i want to check whether there is value in `compare date range`. If the user doesn't set the `compare date range` value, i want to warn him when he clicks `submit` button. And also if the user doesn't set the `above date range`, i should warn him when he clicks the `submit` button.
Please help me with some solutions.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker, Checkbox} from 'antd';
import moment from "moment";
class DateCheck extends React.Component {
    state = { startDate:moment(),endDate:moment(),dateCompareEntry:true,cstartDate:moment(),cendDate:moment()}

    onDateChange(date) {this.setState({startDate:date[0]['_d'],endDate: date[1]['_d']})}
    onInitialDateSet(){
        var end_date = new Date();
        end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate()-15)
        this.setState({startDate:new Date(), endDate:end_date})
    }
    onDateCompareCheckClick(e){this.setState({dateCompareEntry:e.target.checked?false:true})}
    onCompareDateChange(date) {this.setState({cstartDate:(date[0]['_d']),cendDate: date[1]['_d']})}
    onSubmitFun(){console.log("submit Fun")}
    onCancelFun(){
        console.log("cancel Fun")
        var end_date = new Date();
        end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate()-15)
        this.setState({startDate:new Date(), endDate:end_date})
        this.setState({dateCompareEntry:true,cstartDate:moment(),cendDate:moment()})

    }
    componentDidMount(){this.onInitialDateSet()}
    render() {
        const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
        return (
            <div style = {{display:"flex",justifyContent:"flex-end", width:"100%"}} >    
                <RangePicker 
                    renderExtraFooter={() => 
                        <div style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"column"}}>
                            <div >
                                <Checkbox onChange = {(e)=>{this.onDateCompareCheckClick(e)}}>Compare With</Checkbox>
                                <RangePicker 
                                    size={'small'}
                                    disabled={this.state.dateCompareEntry} 
                                    onChange ={this.onCompareDateChange.bind(this)}
                                    >
                                </RangePicker>
                            </div>
                            <div style={{marginBottom:"1%",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center"}}>
                                <div>
                                    <Button  onClick={this.onSubmitFun.bind(this)}  size="small" type="primary" icon="search">Submit</Button>
                                </div>
                                <div style={{marginLeft:"2%"}}>
                                    <Button onClick={this.onCancelFun.bind(this)} size="small" type="danger" icon="close-circle">Cancel</Button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    } 
                    defaultValue={[ moment(this.state.startDate),moment(this.state.endDate)]} 
                    style={{width:'40%'}} size={'small'} 
                    onChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)} />  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default DateCheck
```

Answer (score 1):

Use open property for opening DatePicker/RangePicker like this sample :

this handler just open DatePicker when you ckick input box but that's don't close with any other click !

```
  handleJustOpenDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ openDatePicker: true });
  };
```

for closing need another handler like button onClick like this :

```
  handleDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ openDatePicker: !this.state.openDatePicker });
  };
```

Full sample :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import { DatePicker, version } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { openDatePicker: false };
  }

  handleDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ openDatePicker: !this.state.openDatePicker });
  };

  handleJustOpenDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ openDatePicker: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: 32 }}>
        <p style={{ marginBottom: 24 }}>Date Picker Test</p>
        <button style={{ marginBottom: 32 }} onClick={this.handleDatePicker}>
          Click to open/Close PDate Picker
        </button>
        <br />

        <div onClick={this.handleJustOpenDatePicker}>
          <DatePicker
            defaultValue={moment()}
            open={this.state.openDatePicker}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer output : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-react-date-picker-yrhu4)